# RelativeLayout with optional/conditional relationship for positioning

Tags: android, xml

I have 4 buttons `A,B,C,D` on a `RelativeLayout`.

The button C is sometimes visible, sometimes not - depending on some condition which is set expliticly everytime before the layout appears.

If all buttons are visible I like to position the buttons like this:

A

B

C

D

Otherwise if C is not visible like this

A

B

D

Since I use `android:layout_below="@+id/buttonX"` to position the buttons I do not know what to do with the conditional C and D buttons.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Code your whole activity programmable, don't use XML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I don't like nesting views, a simple solution would be to include your bottom two buttons in a LinearLayout

Ex.

```
<RelativeLayout>

     <A>
     <B>

     <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
       <C>
       <D>
     </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

That way you can set the LinearLayout below B and it wouldn't matter if C or D was missing

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I set the parent programmatically in code using:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();

if (reliantViewVisible) {
  lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.reliantView);
} else {
  lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.fallbackView);
}
```

If the next element is the initial parent, this might work for you in XML

`android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"`

Answer (score -1):

RelativeLayout will already do what you want for you.  It will automatically place D below B if C's visibility is 'gone'.

Comment: actually it does not work in my case - defining "D under C" if C is missing results in D being positioned at the very top of the screen...